# Knowrob installation: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [libmongocxx_ros]

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosdep, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to install on ROS Melodic
getting this error

```
rosdep install --ignore-src --from-paths .
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
mongodb_log: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [libmongocxx_ros]
```

Anyone succeeded installing the library?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352056/knowrob-installation:-cannot-locate-rosdep-definition-for-%5Blibmongocxx_ros%5D/) by [vincentS](https://answers.ros.org/users/54837/vincents/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check this https://github.com/knowrob/knowrob/issues/231. In addition to installing libmongoc-dev as mentioned in the link, you need to install python-rrdtool, libjson-glib-1.0 , python-rdflib.

---

Originally posted by [Kavya](https://answers.ros.org/users/54865/kavya/) with karma: 16 on 2020-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0